# Android Voice Actions: set-alarm intent

Tags: android, android-intent

What is the intent to handle the "set alarm" Voice Action?
(For "listen to" it is android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not use the standard `android.intent.action.SET_ALARM` from the [`android.provider.AlarmClock`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html) class?

Comment: I guess the right way to access this string-constant is android.provider.AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM

Comment: Interesting: You can only set hour and minutes. So either android.intent.extra.alarm.DAY_OF_YEAR will become a hidden feature or you can only set alarms for the next day/morning.